# Pandas merge two data frames on a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two different dataframes df1 and df2 which I would like to merge based on the following condition:

```
id     category
1      cat1
2      cat2
```

df2:

```
id      category_name
1       shoes
1       car
```

resultant df:

```
id    category     category_name
1     cat1         shoes
1                  car
2     cat2
```

I don't want to the cat1 to be repeating while the merge happens. I only want to keep the id and the column category_name value that I am trying to store. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
>>> (df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
        .assign(category=lambda x: x['category'].mask(x['category'].duplicated()))
        .fillna(''))

   id category category_name
0   1     cat1         shoes
1   1                    car
2   2     cat2
```

Comment: I was about to post something similar but you were faster, +1 ;) https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8iIB.png

Comment: This time only, usually you're faster than me ;-)

Comment: The competitiveness in this tag is off the charts these days - ol' timers like myself can't keep up 